# Redundancy in the definition of Dedekind domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

> Is there a domain which is noetherian and whose nonzero prime ideals
>   are maximal, but which is not integrally closed?

This may be a silly question to experts. I ask because I think I have found proofs for the following implications:

1. Noetherian domain whose nonzero prime ideals are maximal $\implies$
2. Every fractional ideal is projective/invertible $\implies$
3. Fractional ideals form an abelian group under multiplication $\implies$
4. *Integrally closed* noetherian domain whose nonzero prime ideals are maximal

But I can't find an error on first inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are such domains: for instance, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ or $k[X^2,X^3]$. These are not integrally closed, but they are noetherian of dimension one.